# CASE in SQL Server with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, conditional-statements, case

I am working in SQL Server to generate some results. I have two columns, `Auth` and `DOB` and three conditions to consider:

1. Auth has Y then DOB will have date pf birth without any special character in the format yyyymmdd
2. Auth has N and the age is less than or equal to 89 then we enter the DOB
3. Auth has N and the age is more than 89 then we just enter the year 1900

The issue is since I am using DATE type for DOB, it's creating an issue for the the third condition since it is only in yyyy format.

This is the code that I am using

```
CASE 
   WHEN Auth IN ('Y', 'YES') 
      THEN CAST(REPLACE(DOB, '-', '') AS DATE)
   WHEN Auth IN ('N', 'NO') AND DATEDIFF(YEAR, DOB@TODAY) <= 89 
      THEN YEAR(DOB)
   WHEN Auth IN ('N', 'NO') AND DATEDIFF(YEAR, DOB@TODAY) > 89 
      THEN '1900'
   ELSE '' 
END AS BIRTHDATE
```

Can anyone please help me on how to do it with case itself?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: *"Auth has Y then DOB will have date pf birth without any special character in the format yyyymmdd"* what do you mean by this? Date and time values aren't stored in formats, they are binary values, so it *can't* have any special characters.

Comment: Well, `'1900'` isn't a date. So what datatype do you want it to be? `date` or `varchar`? Supply the datatype you need. All paths of a case expression should end in the same datatype.

Comment: Assuming that this works `WHEN Auth IN ('N','NO') AND DATEDIFF(YEAR,DOB@TODAY)<=89 THEN YEAR(DOB)`. I don't know what is stopping you from doing `WHEN Auth IN ('N','NO') AND DATEDIFF(YEAR,DOB@TODAY)>89 THEN YEAR('1900-01-01')`

Comment: For starters, `DATEDIFF(YEAR,DOB@TODAY)` (or `DATEDIFF(YEAR,DOB,@TODAY)`) doesn't give you the age of someone, @ArpitChinmay .

Comment: `DATEDIFF(YEAR,DOB,@TODAY)` if he has defined a variable @TODAY=GETDATE() then it should probably give age in years

Comment: @ArpitChinmay do many people consider someone born six months ago to be a 1 year old? `select datediff(year, '2020-12-20', '2021-05-20');`

Comment: It helps with questions like this to present an example data set and the schema see [mre]

Comment: @AlwaysLearning  well it depends on the use case. Considering he/she is calculating age in years. 6 months (0.5 years) should roundoff to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It looks like you were getting a type clash in the second condition, which was returning an INT data type. Your statement said the second condition should return the DOB as is, which should be a VARCHAR data type to align with the other conditions of the CASE statement.

```
SELECT  CASE
            WHEN LEFT(Auth, 1) = 'Y' THEN FORMAT(DOB, 'yyMMdd')
            WHEN LEFT(Auth, 1) = 'N'
                 AND DATEDIFF(YEAR, DOB, @TODAY) <= 89 THEN CAST(DOB AS VARCHAR)
            WHEN LEFT(Auth, 1) = 'N'
                 AND DATEDIFF(YEAR, DOB, @TODAY) > 89 THEN '1900'
            ELSE ''
        END AS BIRTHDATE
FROM    dbo.children AS c;
```